# PostGIS ST_Difference function returns wrong geometry in result

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geoprocessing, intersection, overlapping-features

I have a strange `st_difference` behaviour. I’ve got two overlapping lines (each one has two points), but `st_difference` result is complete geometry of the first line.

The code to reproduce is here:

```
WITH
mylines AS
(
SELECT
 st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(4377625.44 7399187.54,4377633.47 7398278.09)') as ro_geom,
 st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(4377625.44 7399187.54,4377630.67957507 7398594.12386704)') as lk_geom
)

select
  1 as gid,
  st_difference(ro_geom, lk_geom) as diff_geom
from mylines
```

Visually, it looks like this:
[image]

So the `st_difference` between red and blue lines returns a green line, which isn't expected. I'd expect the green line to be shorter and below the blue one (without overlapping it).

This is just a test example I've made for demonstration of the problem. In practice, I'm using `st_difference` for two huge datasets and every difference looks unexpected.

Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the scale of your display, these lines appear to be coincident, but in reality they're not:

[image]

I've exaggerated the difference between the two lines using the "Magnify Topology" tool in [JTS TestBuilder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/), which I highly recommend for looking into cases like this.

Depending on the goal of your analysis, it might be suitable to snap your vertices to a grid first:

```
ST_AsText(ST_Difference(ST_SnapToGrid(ro_geom, 10), ST_SnapToGrid(lk_geom, 10)))
```

Comment: Nice tool, didn't know about that. You beat me to the answer, but another less pretty way of showing the same thing would have been `.... SELECT ST_intersection(ro_geom, lk_geom)) as diff_geom` which, of course, just returns a single point.

Comment: Thanks @dbaston. The smaller line is made by `st_locatebetween` function from the main line. How come it's second node isn't located on the parent line?

Comment: It's the cruel world of floating point numbers.  Vertices that are constructed (from `ST_Intersection`, or `ST_LocateBetween`, or anything else) may not actually intersect the geometries that produced them.

Comment: @dbaston So how can I snap the constructed gometry to match the intial line then?

Comment: read up on ST_Snap. `WITH
mylines AS
(
SELECT
 st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(4377625.44 7399187.54,4377633.47 7398278.09)') as ro_geom,
 st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(4377625.44 7399187.54,4377630.67957507 7398594.12386704)') as lk_geom
)
select
  1 as gid,
  st_astext(st_difference(st_snap(ro_geom, lk_geom, 0.001), st_snap(lk_geom, ro_geom, 0.001))) as diff_geom
from mylines;
`

Comment: This is not how to do it, but you will see it gives the right result. I was playing with this, but dbaston already answered.